# Why Genius doesn't have problems with lyrics copyright?

Tags: copyright, music

I know that lyrics of almost all songs are subject to copyright law (am I right?). But I never heard that Genius (genius.com) where such lyrics are posted without any care had any problems with the copyright law. Do they oblige the copyright law? If yes, how? If not, why music companies don't sue them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do community websites and forums defend against copyright claims?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/19746/how-do-community-websites-and-forums-defend-against-copyright-claims)

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate question and I support it remaining open.  The proposed duplicate question talks about artwork on a personal blog.  This question asks about song lyrics in their entirety for thousands of songs on a commercial product's/service's website.  I do not know whether the ultimate answer would be different, or to what extent, but the question certainly is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genius_(company)#Music_publishing_dispute:

> In 2014, Rap Genius entered into a licensing agreement with music publishers covering both past and future publishing of music lyrics.

Comment: Radio stations do something very similar when they contract for the right to broadcast recorded music.

Comment: Public venues, like restaurants, bars and concert houses make similar arrangements in bulk to pay in advance for the right to have copyrighted works performed on their premises.